# VB Scripting for reading a text file and executing query

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I have a txt file in below format

```
11SNMMMMTESTCASEJBS1961123123232YExist
```

From this file I have to check the value at 33rd column, which will be Y or N.
If it is N, I have to go to database and use below query

```
Update table XYZ set Status = Not Exist where cust_id = ** ( taken from record)
```

if it is Y

```
Update table XYZ set Status = Exist where cust_id = ** ( taken from record)
```

After reading from a text file , I am trying to connect to SQLplus with a value stored in a variable and trying to update a table but I am getting below error : " Unterminated String constant
Here is what code looks like, thanks to Guido for helping me out on Step 1.
Can anyone please point out the error . Some error inside If & Else Part , the SQL query or connection is wrong

```
dim fs, txt, line, yesno , cust_id
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set txt = fs.OpenTextFile("E:\batchfiletest\Eapp3\scotia1.txt", 1, false) 

' loop through all the lines
do while not txt.AtEndOfStream
    line = txt.readLine

' read the character and store it in a variable
    yesno = Mid(line, 127, 1)
    cust_id = Mid(line, 1,20)   

' execute the correct query
    if yesno = "Y" then

    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set oEnv=WshShell.Environment("Process") 
    cmdString = "E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\sqlplusw.exe -S sysman/csaadmin@convcsd

    UPDATE csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote set HOLD_CODE = 'CAQ' where quote_id =  cust_id ;
    commit;"

    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(cmdString)

     ELSE  
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    set oEnv=WshShell.Environment("Process") 
    cmdString = "E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\sqlplusw.exe -S sysman/csaadmin@convcsd

    UPDATE csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote set HOLD_CODE = 'PVQ' where quote_id =  cust_id ;
    commit;"

    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(cmdString)

    end if
loop
MsgBox "Press OK to close when done reading the output."
```

Comment: you appear to be asking SO to write your code for you?

Comment: Pointers can help me, a code is even better :)

Comment: Did you take a look at the links I've included in my answer below? It is pretty basic code. Let me know if that works for you, otherwise I can write u an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the vbscript [String](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp) functions. Look specifically for the [Mid](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp) function.

You then should be able to read specific character positions, and execute the correct query.

Example for reading lines from a text file, storing character from the line and using it later on:

```
dim fs, txt, line, yesno

' create a file system object and open the text file
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set txt = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\dgaurav\Deskto‌​p\CSA -3\scotia.txt", 1, false) 

' loop through all the lines
do while not txt.AtEndOfStream
    line = txt.readLine

    ' read the character and store it in a variable
    yesno = Mid(line, 33, 1)

    ' execute the correct query
    if yesno = "Y" then
        WScript.Echo "Yes"
    else
        WScript.Echo "No"
    end if
loop
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of what you are asking for.

Comment: This is my code 

    Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Users\dgaurav\Desktop\CSA -3\scotia.txt",1)
    Dim strLine
    do while not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
         strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
        
      dim yesno : yesno = write(Mid(txt,33,1))
    
       if yesno = "Y" then
        WScript.Echo "Yes"
    else
        WScript.Echo "No"
    end if
    loop
    objFileToRead.Close
    Set objFileToRead = Nothing

This code is not running , getting below error : type mismatch 'write'

Comment: Working like a gem, I have now fetched the Cust_ID also ( first 2 ) and will now try to use them in a query , will see if that works. Thanks for your help Guido .. You ROck :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :). If you upvote my answer and tag it, we are done good sir.

Comment: Needs 15 reputation minimum to increase that counter :( . Will do that once I have it .